# override default docker run from host with options/arguments

Tags: docker

```
FROM alpine:3.5
CMD ["echo", "hello world"]
```

So after building `docker build -t hello .` I can run hello by calling `docker run hello` and I get the output `hello world`.

Now let's assume I wish to run `ls` or `sh` - this is fine. But what I really want is to be able to pass arguments. e.g. `ls -al`, or even `tail -f /dev/null` to keep the container running without having to change the Dockerfile

How do I go about doing this? my attempt at exec mode fails miserably... `docker run hello --cmd=["ls", "-al"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything after the image name in the `docker run` command becomes the new value of `CMD`. So you can run:

```
docker run hello ls -al
```

Note that if an `ENTRYPOINT` is defined, the `ENTRYPOINT` will receive the value of `CMD` as args rather than running `CMD` directly. So you can define an entrypoint as a shell script with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "running the entrypoint code"

# if no args are passed, default to a /bin/sh shell
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  set -- /bin/sh
fi

# run the "CMD" with exec to replace the pid 1 of this shell script
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q. But what I really want is to be able to pass arguments. e.g. ls -al, or even tail -f /dev/null to keep the container running without having to change the Dockerfile

This is just achieved with:

```
 docker run -d hello tail -f /dev/null
```

So the container is running in background, and it let you to execute arbitrary commands inside it:

```
docker exec <container-id> ls -la
```

And, for example a shell:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

Also, I recommend  you what @BMitch says.